# How to manage private dependecies of library with unit tests target in modern target based cmake

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I have a library `A` with public and private dependencies. The unit tests are contained in a separate executable `ATests` which requires to link against both the private and the public dependencies of `A`.

Currently, I explicitly link all private dependencies of `A` to the unit tests `ATest`. This results in a lot of code duplication which becomes increasingly difficult to understand/maintain.

```
add_library(A)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC Pub1 PRIVATE Priv1 Priv2)

add_executable(ATests)
target_link_libraries(ATests PRIVATE A Priv1 Priv2)
```

I thought about creating a separate interface library `APrivDeps` for the private dependencies of `A`, however, this looks like a hack. I have serious doubts that this is portable and will mess up the static linking due to the link dependency propagation. (I would have to export the helper library `APrivDeps`.)

```
add_library(APrivDeps)
target_link_libraries(APrivDeps PUBLIC Priv1 Priv2)

add_library(A)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC Pub1 PRIVATE ADeps)

add_executable(ATests)
target_link_libraries(ATests PRIVATE A ADeps)
```

I expect some method that keeps the configuration short and free of code duplication while still following the target based principle of modern CMake.

Comment: `add_library(APrivDeps INTERFACE)` would look ok

Comment: @KamilCuk this would require to export `APrivDeps` as it needs to be visible to targets linking to `A` in case `A` is a static library.

Comment: Yes it would need. Is that a bad thing? Right now `Priv1` and `Priv2` are visible anyway, you just group it. You can name it what you want, ex.  `A_PRIV_DEP_ONLY_FOR_INTERNAL_USE` and everyone will know it's only for internal use in A library.

Comment: @KamilCuk This means that `APrivDeps` will end up in the generated CMake config file too. Installing necessary implementation details on other systems seems odd. Can you turn your comment into an answer, so that I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to explicitly propagate private dependencies. One way to do this is with the [TARGET_PROPERTY generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_PROPERTY).

```
add_library(A)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC Pub1 PRIVATE Priv1 Priv2)

add_executable(ATests)
target_link_libraries(ATests PRIVATE A $<TARGET_PROPERTY:A,LINK_LIBRARIES>)
```

It may also be necessary to propagate other properties like `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `COMPILE_OPTIONS`, and so on. This does feel a bit like breaking the target based principle of modern CMake so use judiciously. To me it seems to be a reasonable approach for unit tests.